# Absolute position div container in a div float

Tags: css

All, I knew if the absolute position child div wasn't set the `left` property, then this child div's default begin position will be in the parent div. but the absolute div's width isn't limited by the parent div's width. 
But If we set value to it's TLRB property. then as the [w3cschool tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) says .`The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.`
My question is how to make the absolute position child div container in a div? 
A method I can figure out is using the javascript to calculate and set the width proper value.
But I want to know if it could be made by css. thanks.

Comment: Not really related to the question itself, but do take some time to read http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a parent div has `position:relative`, and a child has `position:absolute; width:100%`, then child would have the same width as parent. [Check at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qyy2W/)

Comment: Could you please tell me more about it . what is the css rule in it? thanks.

Comment: Browser looks up to element`s parents and serch for the first one with `positioned` and makes it container for element. Important to know 2 tips: 1. if there is no such elements upstream - `<html>` tag become container 2. (I think it`s most important) **Container may be not the first parent**, this one may be really confusing. [Check this extended example](http://jsfiddle.net/Qyy2W/2/). More information [at W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#comp-abspos) and [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning)

Comment: Very good demo to explain the `absolute`, It is helpful for me on the way of from newbie to pro in web development. I didn't found the specification in w3c offical website is informative . thanks .